# n being registered as punctuation in grep, R

Tags: r, punctuation

For some reason the letter 'n' is being registered as punctuation with grep.

```
test="n"
grepl("[:punct:]",test)
```

returns TRUE

Does anyone else have this problem?

Comment: My guess is that this would return true for "p" or "u" as well. Make sure that the syntax is correct for "[:punct;]" expression, or the `grepl` actually expects it. Hint: there is an example in the grepl docs that look different than this when using those forms of regex.

Answer (score 1):

We need to have to have an enclosing square bracket

```
grepl("[[:punct:]]",test)
#[1] FALSE
```